# How to do segmentation of connected components in openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I have to segment out each individual element in [this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56apy.jpg). I have converted the original image to a threshold binary image and then applied some morphological dilation. Then I applied the *cv::connectedComponents* function to label each connected components. Now I want to crop out them, how can I do it using c++ and openCV ?

Comment: They already should have a label... so you can just loop the pixels and get the number, and copy just the ones with the desired label to another image. You can also copy with a mask the you create on the moment like `copyImage.setTo(cv::Scalar(255,255,255), labelImage == 4)` in this example 4 is the desired label

Answer (score 0):

If instead of using connectedComponents use connectedComponentsWithStats, you should have enough information for cropping each of the objects labeled.

Comment: Thanks @TFreitas !! Considering that I am new to openCV could you pl explain in little more detail on how can I crop the individual elements ? I printed the number of connected components returned by the function, which is 559, now I want to separate them ? How to do it ? Kindly help me in solving this.

Comment: wil connectedComponentsWithStats you will have a Mat with the stats of each object:

cv::Mat labels, stats, centroids;
int numberofObjects = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(Image, labels, stats, centroids, 8, CV_16U);

If you see in documentation you'll see that those stats have the length and the height of the bounding box of each object. To cut them just acess the atributes as:

for (int label = 1; label < numberofObjects; label++) {
width = stats.at<int>(label, CC_STAT_HEIGHT);
height = stats.at<int>(label, CC_STAT_WIDTH);
Use this info to cut the ROI for each object

Comment: Great, Glad to help!